# How to Receive a data from activemq to Server Socket(using netty) using apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, serversocket

Basically what I am doing is that I am send data from server Socket (using netty) to activemq and then want to read the data from activemq to server Socket (using netty), from Server Socket to activemq I am successfully able to read the data but when I am trying to read the same data from activemq to Server Socket then my server socket is not able to read the data.

These are the following things what I tried and got errors

Intially I got this error "org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis" , so to resolve this error I have tried two arguments in my activemq is **ExchangePattern.InOnly** and **disableRepltTo=false/true(both)**, Although from this, my exception went off but still my ServerSocket is not able to read the data from activemq to serverSocket

Here is my code

```
from("netty:tcp://localhost:6665")
.log("log:Sending message from -->${body}")
.to("activemq:Test");
        
from("activemq:Test?exchangePattern=InOnly")
.log("log:Sending message from -->${body}")
.to("netty:tcp://localhost:6666?textline=true&sync=false&clientMode=true");
```

Comment: Is `telnet localhost 6666` responding something or not ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco No, In the logs it is showing nothing, and Thanks for responding for the question